# Swift segue running even though if statment is not true

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, segue

I am trying to stop the segue running if there is no text in the text field

```
@IBAction func action(_ sender: Any) {
    if( email.text != ""){
        emailaddress = email.text!
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
    }
    else
    {
        print("enter a email")
    }
}
```

The "enter email" prints out in the output but it still performs the segue.

Comment: are you sure you didn't attached your segue to your button ?

Comment: If that code prints "enter a email" then that code isn't performing the segue. It's happening for some other reason.

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the segue between view controller not button to view controller. see the image

[image]

After that call this method on button with condition

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't attach your segue to your button, because if the segue is directly attached to the button, the performSegue will perform through the click and not through the line

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
```

Just drag and drop your segue from the yellow icon to the next controller

Comment: Another alternative is to have the segue on the button and implement `shouldPerformSegue` in your view controller - if you return `false` from this method then the segue will be cancelled